# Is it possible to use global options in P4.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, perforce, p4.net

I am using P4.NET to control perforce programmatically but there doesn't seem to be a way to specify global options like this:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/o.gopts.html

Maybe someone else has an experience on how to do this?

Comment: What option are you interested in setting? And have you tried putting the option in front of the command you pass to Run()?

Comment: Thanks Mike, I tried that, but didn't work. But like Dennis' answer I figured it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the global environment values using the `P4Connection` class like so

```
P4Connection p4 = new P4Connection();   
p4.Host = "127.0.0.1";    
p4.Port = 1666;   
p4.User = "joan.verge";   
p4.Client = "joanverge_main";
```

If these values are not set, it will use the environment settings set in your client configuration file or windows registry (for *Linux* and *OSX* there is a configuration file in the ~.p4 directory).

If you use Perforce via the command line I would *highly* recommend you set up a client configurations (Note: I only know how to do this on Windows, refer to P4 KB for other platforms).

First set your global environment settings using the command line.

```
p4 set P4USER=joan.verge
p4 set P4PORT=127.0.0.1:1666
```

To test the above have been set correctly, use `p4 info`.

Next, put the workspace/client specific settings into a text file named `p4config` (no extension) and place it in the root of your workspace/client.

```
P4CLIENT=joanverge_main
```

Set one more environment variable,

```
p4 set P4CONFIG=p4config
```

Copy the `p4config` file to another workspace/client, edit the `P4CLIENT` variable to match.

Now on the command line, navigate to both directories and compare the `p4 info` command.

Also, setting this up allows you to use the P4 windows explorer navigation across multiple workspaces.

**Edit:** you might find this StackOverflow question useful that was *answered* by Mike a few months ago with setting the `Charset` property: [P4.Net and P4CHARSET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240500/p4-net-and-p4charset).

Comment: Thanks man, I wish I have seen this sooner. Found it while fiddling with the P4Connection p4 object. But thanks for the detailed answer, it helps big time.

Comment: Also just out of curiosity, I only set the client and do operations on that client. Is this enough? Do I also need to set the user, port and host, etc? Setting only the client seems to work fine. But I don't know P4 as much.

Comment: Whatever you do not set **will** be taken from the environment variables as needed. How much do you trust your users that they will have their Perforce set up correctly?

Comment: Following up on what Dennis said, I would definitely choose to be explicit about setting user, host, and port. It's a little more code, but it can save you some time debugging why connections suddenly stopped working, only to realize that P4USER or P4PORT were changed.

Comment: I agree with Mike. I believe in our integration of P4 we sanity check the environment variables and prompt the user with a connection dialog (with the information we know pre-filled) if anything is amiss. When you do the sanity checking log the results (you are using a logger right?) and when something goes wrong it will be easier to spot that P4USER is null etc.

Comment: Thanks guys I will be sure to use them then. So host, port, user, client is enough to make it as robust as possible? Also it's 1 person every PC, does the user change? Like only 1 possible user can be using a workspace, right? Or are you guys saying, it's all like that, but if they still wrote some wrong data into the env variables, it's gonna fail, and perforce isn't gonna figure it out from the server side. I guess that's what you mean.

Comment: Also guys instead of strong all these values separately, is it not better to make an object with those values and pass them or something? Just curious how you do it.

Comment: That is a design decision for you; I would be inclined to create a  class `P4Environment` that wraps all these values and has a static methods for sanity checking etc. However, before you rush off to implement this first have a look to see if one is included in P4.NET.

Comment: What about the global flags that are not present in the environment variables, e.g. -I option to get the progress indicator?