# Is there a way to undo remember encoding in Perforce Client?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I accidentally set encoding to Western European and clicked the don't ask me again box in Perforce Client.  I now can't check any of my changes into the code base.  Is there a way to undo this?

Google says to set the p4charset back to none (the server is in Unicode), so that's what I want, but even after running the cmd line command p4 -C none, it's still set to western.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No access to P4 client now , following are answers from google. HTH

Did you try this solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5332788/705315

P4CHARSET can also be set using config files : http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/02_config.html